# How do I forward a mail message as an attachment in MS Graph?

Tags: email, microsoft-graph-api, attachment, forward

I'm retrieving all the messages from a given mailbox, and if one of them contains problematic attachments, I want to send an email to the sender of that message, explaining the problem, and including the original email as an attachment.

I need to either put the message into a stream, or save it to the filesystem.  I imagine the former would be better, but I can't see any methods that can do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How big are the attachments that you want to forward? With the Graph there is a 4MB limit that you will hit with some of the endpoints that will restrict the methods you can use to do this. Eg if all the Messages are under 4MB then you could either attachment them as an Item attachment https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/message-post-attachments?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http but for your purposes you'll loose fidelity on things like Internet Message headers which won't help with working out what's gone wrong with the message. Probably what you want to do is download the message first as MIME https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-get-mime-message save it as an Eml file and then attach that file. If you need to deal with 4MB+ emails you need to check the size and use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-large-attachments?tabs=http when necessary.